# LinkedIn follow button not transparent

Tags: javascript, css, transparency, linkedin-api

I have a LinkedIn button on my website on top of a dark background, but the corners of the rounded LinkedIn button are white making it square looking. Is there anyway to make it transparent?

```
<li class="item-3">
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
type="text/javascript">
lang: en_US
</script>
```

I have tried `background-color: transparent;` in CSS but nothing happens. Adding `background-color: white;` makes a big white box around the whole LinkedIn button, so I assume `transparent` does work, but just not where I want it to.

[image]

Comment: Try setting `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` or whatever

Comment: That just changes the background of the box that the LinkedIn button is in, its like the LinkedIn button is separate from the box that it is in. Probably something to do with the JS.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: If you suspect the CSS is being set via JS, then you may well have to use JS to set it yourself.  The alternative is judicious use of the CSS !important rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support from linkedin is laughable... I've contacted them re this issue. They refuse to acknowledge it. And have instead pointed me here: [LinkedIn Homepage Redesign](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/global/a_id/2756)

This does not resolve the issue (obviously).

The style cannot be overwritten using css. I am going to remove the follow button, as this is the only available option. Great job LinkedIn...

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that can be reproduced on LinkedIn's own [Plugin Generator Page](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company) by changing the background color of the `#widget` element.

The culprit is this code on LinkedIn's server:

```
.framed #body .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Since this code is on another domain you cannot override it with your own CSS or JavaScript. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe#comment10206625_217833) for example.)

Update 2015-06-19: LinkedIn has fixed the issue.