# Linkedin follow company button background issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, linkedin-api

I'm trying to add a a Linkedin follow button to my page using the iframe method:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="1337" data-counter="top"></script>
```

The button is rendered and everything is happy. But then I noticed that the area behind the count bubble is set to have a background color of white, which is a problem when the page background is not white. It's also in an iframe within an iframe within an iframe so I can't really play around with CSS too much to fix it.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Only LinkedIn can fix this issue. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28845113/1221212).

Comment: Problem is linkedin doesn't seem too keen on fixing anything. Their tech support submission form was all bugged up when I tried to report this.